# Change the size of a JTextField inside a JBorderLayout

Tags: java, resize, size, jframe, jtextfield

When I use the code below it doesn't alter the size at all, it still fills the area in the grid.

```
JPanel displayPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 2));

JTextField titleText = new JTextField("title");

displayPanel.add(titleText);

titleText.setSize(200, 24);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the api on GridLayout:

> The container is divided into
>   equal-sized rectangles, and one
>   component is placed in each rectangle.

Try using FlowLayout or GridBagLayout for your set size to be meaningful. Also, @Serplat is correct. You need to use [setPreferredSize( Dimension )](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setPreferredSize(java.awt.Dimension)) instead of [setSize( int, int )](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setSize(java.awt.Dimension)).

```
    JPanel displayPanel = new JPanel();
    // JPanel displayPanel = new JPanel( new GridLayout( 4, 2 ) );
    // JPanel displayPanel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
    // JPanel displayPanel = new JPanel( new GridBagLayout() );

    JTextField titleText = new JTextField( "title" );

    titleText.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 200, 24 ) );

    // For FlowLayout and GridLayout, uncomment:
    displayPanel.add( titleText );

    // For BorderLayout, uncomment:
    // displayPanel.add( titleText, BorderLayout.NORTH );

    // For GridBagLayout, uncomment:
    // displayPanel.add( titleText, new GridBagConstraints( 0, 0, 1, 1, 1.0,
    // 1.0, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.NONE,
    // new Insets( 0, 0, 0, 0 ), 0, 0 ) );
```

Comment: I like the GridBagLayout after doing a bit of research on it. However, what do the two sets of numbers mean? The ones after the first bracket and the ones in and around Insets?

Comment: The api will explain it better than I:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#GridBagConstraints%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20double,%20double,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.Insets,%20int,%20int%29

Answer (score 2):

With a BorderLayout you need to use `setPreferredSize` instead of `setSize`

Answer (score 1):

Try to play with

```
setMinSize()
setMaxSize()
setPreferredSize()
```

These method are used by layout when it decide what should be the size of current element. The layout manager calls setSize() and actually overrides your values.

Answer (score 1):

Any component added to the GridLayout will be resized to the same size as the largest component added. If you want a component to remain at its preferred size, then wrap that component in a JPanel and then the panel will be resized:

```
JPanel displayPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 2)); 
JTextField titleText = new JTextField("title"); 
JPanel wrapper = new JPanel( new FlowLayout(0, 0, FlowLayout.LEADING) );
wrapper.add( titleText );
displayPanel.add(wrapper); 
//displayPanel.add(titleText);
```